# Integrating Cucumber test results from azure pipeline to update testcases status in azure testplan

Tags: java, intellij-idea, azure-devops, cucumber, test-plan

I'm encountering an issue related to associating test results with an Azure Test Plan. I'm running my Cucumber test cases in an Azure DevOps pipeline, and I need to link these results to a specific test plan. I've been attempting to achieve this using the Azure DevOps API, but I haven't been successful so far.

Has anyone else faced this problem and found a solution?

I successfully created a pipeline for executing the test cases. However, when I attempted to use the DevOps API to update the results, it didn't work as expected. I'm now looking for a solution to associate the test results with my test plan.